# Giving water to strangers

Tags: mad-max

If I give water to strangers in the wastes, does that affect the story in any way? If I refuse to give water to anyone, will that come back to bite me later on? Do strangers take the same amount of water each time? For example, do ones that are crawling on the ground take more than those who are walking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving water to strangers, or not doing so, does not appear to affect the story and I think the amount of water given should be consistent.

Giving water to strangers will sometimes do nothing, but on occasion it will lead to scavenge points being revealed on your map. Additionally, as described in [this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gXoVUljGs-sJ:https://steamcommunity.com/app/234140/discussions/0/527274088394769740/%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=opera) Steam Community thread, it seems like giving water may also bring up your legend level.